# How to pass filtered array to another component without affecting main array Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Hi I am trying to implement a search functionality in which I need to pass my filtered (searched array) to another functional component and if no search then need to pass main array which I got by API response. But whenever I am trying to do that it's resetting the filtered one by `useState` hook.

Here's an example :

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext, useMemo } from "react";
    import { Search} from "carbon-components-react";
    import { debounce } from 'lodash';

    const ComponentA = () => { 
     const arr = [
      {
       name: "GARCIA, LALITA M",
       fname: "LALITA",
       lname: "GARCIA",
       mname: "M",
       id: "lxgFfg",
       userType: "FRN",
       userStatus: "A",
       type: "User",
       brands: [
          "PHI"
        ]
      },
     {
       name: "ANDREW, DONALD M",
       fname: "DONALD",
       lname: "ANDREW",
       mname: "M",
       id: "lxgHJg",
       userType: "FRN",
       userStatus: "A",
       type: "User",
       brands: [
          "PHI"
        ]
      }
    ]; 

   // just here I put hard coded array but we got similar array from API and every time array is different as per API response.

   const [unassignedStoresList, setUnassignedStoresList] = useState(arr);
   
   const searchStoreLists = (value) => {

       if(unassignedStoresList.length === 0) return;
       if(value !== ""){
         let searchArr = [...unassignedStoresList];
         let searchableArr = searchArr.filter((ele) => {
            let searchValue = ele.name.toLowerCase();
            let searchId = ele.id.toLowerCase();
              return (searchValue.indexOf(value) !== -1 || searchId.indexOf(value) !== -1);
            });
          setUnassignedStoresList(searchableArr); // once modified
       } else {
          setUnassignedStoresList(unassignedStoresList); // Not setting original array if search is off
       }
  }
  return(
     <Search
         light
         closeButtonLabelText="Search"
         id="search-1"
         labelText="Search User"
         onChange={ debounce((event) => {
           searchStoreLists(event.target.value);
         }, 500)}
         size="lg"
      /> 
    <ComponentB
        unassignedStoresList={unassignedStoresList}
    />
  );
}
```

I am new to react please help me what I am doing wrong here. Thanks..!!

Comment: There is an error in your code that I can see. "let searchId = ele.id.toLowerCase()" In this statement you are treating array as Object which will cause error. You need to pass ele , id as the callBack parameters in your filter function;

Comment: No. the function runs fine @TarunKumarSao

Comment: Your original array is not unassignedStoresList but arr that you are passing to useState for initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Your original array is not unassignedStoresList but arr that you are passing to useState for initialization. Thus, replace

else {
setUnassignedStoresList(unassignedStoresList); // Not setting original array if search is off
}

with

else {
setUnassignedStoresList(arr); // Not setting original array if search is off
}

I hope this helps you. If not, please do mention that.

Comment: Nope I tried that. Actually consider `arr` is coming from API response and I am setting it into `const [unassignedStoresList, setUnassignedStoresList] = useState(arr);`. So basically arr is not constant like I mentioned it might be different as per API response.

Comment: Let me know if still didn't get. I will modify question by putting api call inside `useEffect`.

Comment: But the thing is that when you change the value of unassignedStoresList using your search functionality, the value has been changed as is not the original value anymore.

Comment: I think you need to store the data you receive from the API call to some variable first. Then use that variable for this purpose.

Comment: I solved by using another useState which contains main response array. Thanks..!!